# Apresentar dados na tabela

Tags: php, html5, cakephp, tabela-html, table

Estou a tentar apresentar estes itens deste modo: [image: Tabela 1]

No entanto após várias tentativas a tabela continua sempre assim:
[image: Tabela 2]

Como devo fazer a tabela para obter este resultado?

**View**

```
<h2>Apagar evento</h2>
<br>
<table border="1" width "100px" bordercolor="#e2e2e2"  style="word-wrap: break-word" cellpadding="10px">
<tr>
    <?php
    $i=0;
    foreach( $showbills as $showbill ):?>

        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink('Apagar Evento', array('controller'=> 'showbills', 'action'=>'admin_del_event', $showbill['Showbill']['id_showbill']), array('class'=>'event_del', 'title'=>'Apagar Evento'),__('Tem a certeza que quer apagar este Evento?'));?>
        </th>

    <tr>
        <td style="display:inline-block">
            <?php echo $showbill['Showbill']['title'];?>
        </td>
        <td style="display:inline-block">
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('showbill/' . $showbill['Showbill']['image'], array('width' => '189px', 'height' => '267px', 'alt' => $showbill['Showbill']['image']));?>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
        if($i==3){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;
        }
    ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Parece que tem um erro de sintax aqui `<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach( $showbills as $showbill ):?>` acho que o correto seria com `;` `<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach( $showbills as $showbill );?>`

Comment: Não, ele está correcto desta forma também.

Comment: Eu recomendo você fazer isso sem tabela, principalmente por se tratar de dados dinâmicos, daqui a pouco mostro um exemplo de como ficaria o html e css para resolver seu problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal para este casos é usar [html](/questions/tagged/html) e [css](/questions/tagged/css)

sua **View** ficaria assim:

```
<?php foreach( $showbills as $showbill ):?>
<div class="events">
    <div class="title">
        <?php echo $this->Form->postLink('Apagar Evento', array(
            'controller'=> 'showbills', 
            'action'=>'admin_del_event', 
            $showbill['Showbill']['id_showbill']
        ), array(
            'class'=>'event_del', 
            'title'=>'Apagar Evento'
        ),__('Tem a certeza que quer apagar este Evento?'));?>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><?php echo $showbill['Showbill']['title'];?></div>
    <div class="image"> 
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('showbill/' . $showbill['Showbill']['image'], array(
            'width' => '189px', 
            'height' => '267px', 
            'alt' => $showbill['Showbill']['image']
        ));?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

E adicionar o seguinte ao seu [css](/questions/tagged/css):

```
.events {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.title {
    color: blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.text {
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;

}

.image {
    width: 139px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

A classe `event` deve possuir exatamente 1/3 do tamanho da sua área destinada para o conteúdo. Você pode substituir o valor fixo por 33%, desta forma o layout se adapta à tela d dispositivo.

Outra opção seria usar [grid-layout](/questions/tagged/grid-layout) para organizar melhor a sua *view*.

Recomendo ler [**este artigo**](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/10/08/css-grid-isso-muda-tudo-de-novo)

Comment: Acrescentei só mais uma `<div>`, que contém estas, para fazer o espaço para as apresentar. Muito obrigado também pelo artigo, que é bastante útil!

Answer (score 0):

Um boa dica é usar o bootstrap, ele é um framework css, bem fácil de usar e de graça (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html)

Após adicionar o framework, você fazer assim:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">imagem 1</div>
  <div class="span4">imagem 2</div>
  <div class="span4">imagem 3</div>
</div>
```